# Add reference to assembly dynamically to MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

Our C# project `Foo` that is built using MSBuild has a compile time dependency on the `Bar.dll` assembly. Problem is, we don't know the location of `Bar.dll`, as it might differ on every developer's computer. To get the location of `Bar.dll` we need to run an executable `locate Bar.dll` and use it's output to add the reference to the assembly to `Foo`. I want to solve this just by modifying the `.csproj` file if possible, no custom build chains, no modifying environment variables.

I know that I can run the `locate` executable in the `BeforeBuild` target using an `<Exec Command="locate Bar.dll" ConsoleToMSBuild=true> ...` node and store it's value in say, property `BarLocation` - but property resolution seems to happen before `BeforeBuild` is executed, so I can't use the `BarLocation` property in the `<Reference Include="${BarLocation}"/>` node. How do I solve this? How can I add a reference to a DLL whose location comes from executing a target?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<ItemGroup>` for the reference inside your `BeforeBuild` target.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <!-- Code to set BarLocation goes here... -->
  <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="$(BarLocation)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```